# How to refresh Android UI from an event listener?

Tags: android, events, android-arrayadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a packet listener that detect when a packet arrived and I need refresh an `ArrayAdapter` when this happens. The problem is that if I try to access the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` method, an Exception is thrown:

```
Exception in packet listener: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() from? It must be from another thread, as in not the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in an object with access to the application's context:

If you are in an `Activity`:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

If you are in a `Fragment`:

```
Activity act = getActivity();
if (act != null) {
    act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Other options exist such as looper/message handler and so on but this is by far the simplest.

Comment: The problem is that I need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after the event occurs to update the UI. For this reason I need to know when an event occurs to update the ui, but I cannot call the method inside the listener because the exception is thrown...

Comment: @user3339544, what class is your adapter in? You can call the method inside the listener by doing the above assuming you are in a fragment or activity. Are you in some other class listener then? If so you will need to get a handler to the the UI thread. Please update the post with some code showing the nature of your listener.